# MvxWpfView inheritence and Visual Studio XAML editor

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

I am creating a Wpf version of our application under MvvmCross (Vee Three).
My views inherit from **MvxWpfView**.
When I try to add an event Handler from XAML editor
(for instance `<Button Click="Click_Handler" />`),
I cannot navigate to the Handler and the association between the xaml and the code-behind is not working.
I can easily work around this by adding the Handler in the constructor, so it's not blocking.

Is it a Visual Studio problem or can something be done in **MvxWpfView** or in the xaml?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried adding a button here using `<Button Click="Click_Handler" />` in the TwitterSearch sample.

After doing this, right clicking and choosing 'Navigate to Event Handler' worked fine.

Can you try getting this working in a new project?

I would guess that the problem might be somewhere in your project/solution

- does your project currently build?
- does the association work after you have done a build?
- can you check that the Xaml and the C# both definitely inherit from MvxWpfView now?

Comment: Hi Stuart, I tried with the TwitterSearch sample, and repoduced the problem. After further investigation, I realised I made some changes in MvxWpfView. I restored the original version and it worked. I then reintroduced my modified version, and now it worked. That beats me!

Comment: Thanks for the update - sounds like you should add your own answer and mark the question as answered. Thanks